# I can't install mongodb in line with manjaro?

Tags: mongodb, archlinux, manjaro

ERROR: Icecream not enabled while using -j higher than available cpu's. Use --force-jobs to override.
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
Aborting...
-> error making: mongodb

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue and it seems to me that this is a result of the default value of the MAKEFLAGS environment variable which sets it to "-j$(($(nproc)+1))".

I changed the value of the variable manually in /etc/makepkg.conf to "-j4" (I think anything lower than the actual number of CPUs will do) which solved the issue for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).